# XNA 4.0 Tutorial?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

Hey Everybody,
    At first this is a "go google it" type of question, but after extensive Googleing I can't seem to find anything. I'm CS major at a University who hopes to go into game programming and I know my Java and C++ and I've even started to dabble into c# by creating a 2D game that had a 3D counter part. The only problem is I don't have a copy of the 3D part to learn from.

Sorry for the long-winded rant, but this is my question;
     Can somebody please point me to a tutorial for using XNA 4.0 (with VS2010) to create a 3D game?!

Comment: google, books: http://www.amazon.com/XNA-Game-Studio-Express-Developing/dp/1598633686 , http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920013709 , https://www.packtpub.com/xna-4-0-game-development-by-example-beginners-guide/book

Comment: msdn online resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is loads of tuturials on youtube this is a basic step by step game tutorial i found. The only problem is that most of the game is static so if you want alot of movement then this would be a starting point but then maybe try check out microsofts msdn site too. Youtube tutorial by XNAMktg2's: http://www.youtube.com/user/XNAMktg2#p/u/41/bWU8bGKT_WQ. Hope that helps also type into google creating xna 4.0 in 60 minutes and a decent tuorial will pop up too. This is a decent starting tutorial that has helped me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940288.aspx.

hope that helps

good luck mate

Answer (score 2):

There is a [*huge* catalogue of 1st-party samples over at App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/).

There's a section for 3D samples. [Here's one complete example](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/starterkit/shipgame).